# Tomcat reference missing from menu and preferences in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, preferences, eclipse-kepler

After spending a few hours searching the internet (including this site), I am unable to find a resolution to my issue and hopefully someone here can help out.

I did a clean install of eclipse kepler (ee version) this morning and my issue is getting Tomcat to be made available on the menu as well as on the preferences tab.

I have set up a Tomcat server in eclipse and have been able to start and stop it without any issue and that has me believing that Tomcat is set-up correctly in eclipse.

A few things tried were to create a dynamic web project hoping this would trigger the addition of the Tomcat options to the menu and preferences screen - nothing here, exited eclipse and re-entered thnking it may need a restart - again nothing.  This instance is current as far as updates are concerned and with it being the ee version, the WTP tools are also installed.

I am thinking something very obvious is being overlooked but I cannot figure that out at the moment.  Any direction you can point me me is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Tom

Comment: What options were you looking for?

Comment: Hi Christopher, by options I meant to see the Tomcat option (for lack of a better term) reside on the Preferences dialog box as you see the General, Ant, Data Management, ... options as well as on a project's Properties dialog box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got this figured out with the help of a co-worker.

I needed to use the Tomcat plug-in (we use the one from Sysdeo) to get this going.  I mistakenly thought that by using the EE edition of Eclipse along with having the webtools plugins (WTP) all that was needed was in place.  Not so.

The downloaded plug-in was extracted into the eclipse/plugins folder.  Once that was done, Eclipse was restarted and the Tomcat references were in place on the menu, the preferences dialog box, and the projects' properties dialog box.

Hope this information will be of value to anyone experiencing the same problem.

Comment: I'm still interested in what "preferences" you want to set that you can't get from the run-configuration.

Comment: The Tomcat items I wanted and was able to set-up only came to reside on the dialog boxes for Preferences and Project Properties after the Sysdeo plugin was used.  That said, I was and still am unaware on how to get those visible when I set-up Tomcat without the plug-in.  That said, the ability to edit the run-configuration for Tomcat was not my issue, it was the other references.  Thanks for following up.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only thing you can do with Tomcat is start it and stop it. What options were you looking for? I think everything you want is under the Tomcat run-configuration that you have already been using. Just edit that run-configuration to set whatever options you want (e.g. heap size, permgen, stack size, debugging options, etc.).